# Is it possible to bind a controller to a particular DS.Model type without going through a route

Tags: ember.js

The particular object in question is a flash object which 0..n maybe returned with each interaction to the backend webservice.

for example transistioning to a route to search for user 1 with the DS sending a request like '/user/1'

could return

```
{
  flash:{
    msg: 'You do not have permission to that user'
    ,flashType: 'warn'
  }
}
```

or

```
{
  flash:{
    msg: 'The user you requested does not exist'
    ,flashType: 'info'
  }
}
```

and I am adding the Flash controller to every route in this manner

```
App.BaseRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  renderTemplate: function () {
    this.render();
    this.render('flash',{
      controller: 'flash'
      ,outlet: 'flash'
    });
  }
});
```

and here is the hack that I am currently using to populate the flashController

```
$(document).ajaxSuccess(function(evt, rqst, settings) {
  if(rqst.getResponseHeader('Content-Type') === 'application/json'
     && rqst.responseText !== ''
     && rqst.responseText !== null){
    var rslt = $.parseJSON(rqst.responseText);
    if(_(rslt).has('flashes')){
      console.log('has Flash');
      var flashController = App.__container__.lookup('controller:flash');
      flashController.set('content', rslt.flashes);
    }
  }
});
```

So, to sum up I see that the DS.Store is creating the flash objects, is there a way to update the flashController while not in the FlashRoute w/o the hack.

Comment: Ok I figured out how to do it by binding to an array to use as a proxy and then used the didLoad event on the model to place it's self in to the proxy.

Comment: I ended up writing a blog post with some gist to show how I solved the problem http://0isthenew1.blogspot.com/2013/12/flash-messages-in-ember-or-how-to-use.html